# Perfomance: Animate CSS Gradient with JS vs SVG Gradient

Tags: javascript, css, performance, svg, gradient

I'm using javascript to animate css `background-image: radial-gradient()`. When the animation is playing the browser feels a bit laggy.

I'm wondering if I point `background-image: url()` to an SVG file with animated gradient, will it work? And more importantly, will it perform better or worse vs css animated with javascript?

Here is my code with javascript:

```
//value is calculated based on the progress of animation, i.e 0% to 100%
const start = value * (value - 75) / 25,//from 75 - 100
mid_black = value * (value - 50) / 19,//from 50 - 75
mid_white = value * (value - 2) / 24,//from 2 - 50
end_dim = value * (value - 2) / 22,//from 2 - 48
end = value * 21;//from 0 - before 5

//elm is the DOM element
elm.style.backgroundImage = 'radial-gradient(farthest-corner, hsla(186, 87%, 40%, 0) '+start+'%, hsla(186, 87%, 5%, .5) '+mid_black+'%, hsl(186, 87%, 80%) '+mid_white+'%, hsla(186, 87%, 40%, .2) '+end_dim+'%, hsla(186, 87%, 40%, 0) '+end+'%)';
```

Comment: Well, it depends on which browser you're using, I know that some browser will handle more easily CSS instead of SVG, but some browser will handle SVGs better than CSS, so, what I recommend is to try 

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try it out. I'm not very good with SVG, so I thought I'd ask first. Good to know it's not consistent between browsers...

Comment: CSS animating the CSS would be more performant. Alternatively SMIL animating an SVG image would work too. I.e. don't use javascript.

Comment: Ok, you can't animate background-image in css, that's why I had to use javascript. Will look into SMIL. Thanks.

Comment: That's wrong, you can animate a background-image with CSS. There are some restrictions but you've not presented much in the way of requirements so I can't tell if you would be affected by them.

Comment: Ok, i'm not aware there are any ways to animate background-image. Would be grateful if you can show me how or point me to an article or something. I just want to have a radial gradient, and then animate it. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you mean animate background-size and background-position? I think that might just work! Thanks for the hint!